# Android: Recyclerview adapter inside recyclerview adapter. How to update data of inside recylcerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I got a recylcerview, which has another recylcerview as an element of it. However, i am confused how to update data of the inside recylcerview. How should I do it?

Comment: Ideally, there should be only one recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you because i don't have your code, but you can create a `updateAdapter` , inside of it you must refresh everything.

For example we have 2 arrayList:

```
private void updateAdapter() {
    this.mItems = c.getArray();
    this.mItemsNr = c.getNr();

    //and call notifyDataSetChanged
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

`mItems` and `MItemsNr` are 2 arrayList and `c` is an object where i have the 2 new `arrayList`.So i update the 2 `arrayList` and hten i call `notifyDataSetChenged();` to update my adapter.

Hope this could help you.